# Pine script Security function differ in return values when called with syminfo.tickerid and Security symbol directly

Tags: security, pine-script

could someone help me with this clarification:

EMA9 calculated using security function, one with syminfo.tickerid and the other one with Security symbol differ in the value returned. Shouldn't they be same? Below is the snippet of code.. Any help is highly appreciated..
Thanks.

```
//EMA9 calculation function
get_Close_EMA9_Stats()=>(close - ta.ema(close,9)) *100 / close

//EMA9 function called using security function passing  syminfo.tickerid and security symbol----
request.security(*syminfo.tickerid*, "W",get_Close_EMA9_Stats() , lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) //Case1
request.security(*"NSE:APOLLOHOSP"*, "W",get_Close_EMA9_Stats() , lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) //Case2
    
//VALUES from Case 1 and 2 DIFFER..SHOULDN'T THEY BE SAME WHEN THE SAME TICKER BEING USED BUT ONE HAVING SYMINFO.TICKERID AND THE OTHER SECURITY SYMBOL DIRECTLY IN THE SECURITY FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try on my end, both `request.security()` calls yield the same result.
Maybe the symbol you have on your chart differs from `NSE:APOLLOSHOP` ?
You can check the value of `syminfo.tickerid` by adding this code at the end of your script.

```
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    var lbl = label.new(na, na, syminfo.tickerid, color=chart.bg_color, textcolor=chart.fg_color)
    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index, high)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Good to know you are getting what is expected.
The tickers are same. Result of your code snippet looks like this:
={"inputs":{},"symbol":"NSE:APOLLOHOSP","type":"BarsSetHeikenAshi@tv-basicstudies-60!"
This result made me to realize that

Comment: Appreciate the response. 

The tickers are same. Result of your code snippet looks like this:
={"inputs":{},"symbol":"NSE:APOLLOHOSP","type":"BarsSetHeikenAshi@tv-basicstudies-60!"

This result made me to realize that I have used HeikenAshi on the chart where in syminfo.tickerid uses Candles type. When i changed the HA to Candles on my layout the values are same.

So I am all set on this. 
Again appreciate your assistance. 
Thanks!